# How to create simple lines with line tool in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tools

I m not very good with photoshop but I m trying to create a very simple shape with line tool, but cannot do it. 
[image: Shape I want]

I m using line tool to draw this and line tool works perfect when I draw lines vertically or horizontally, however when I try to draw something in some other direction it becomes blurry.
[image]

And this is my photoshop settings.

[image: Photoshop Settings]

I have checked and unchecked Anti-alias but nothing works

How do draw smooth line? Any Help

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pen tool, add point of your path, choose your pencil or brush dimension  and go to paths palette and from menu on the top right choose Stroke path! (Maybe the name of the command is some different, I have an italian version, sorry).
Hope it works for you